# npm install no funciona, error `cb() never called!`

Tags: nodejs, npm, yarn

Estoy tratando de instalar las dependencias de un proyecto nuevo , las cuales estan en mi archivo package.json , ejecuto npm install y me da el error `cb() never called!` , he estado investigando , y en algunos sitios dice que hay que limpiar la cache de npm , ya lo hice y trato de volver a instalarlo pero me sigue dando el mismo error. Adicional a esto no se si la carpeta package-lock.json , se genera cuando hago `npm install` o tengo que hacerla yo manualmente?.

Gracias por su tiempo.

Answer (score 0):

No se si solamente sea un problema con usuarios Mac , pero lo he logrado solucionar activando el usuario root , me fui a => Preferencias del sistema->Usuarios y grupos->Acceder.. a servidor de cuentas de red, y en edición le das a activar usuario root.

Luego hice `npm install` y funciono a la perfeccion.